# How can I write the logic for a KDE Plasma Widget written in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, kde-plasma

I'm trying to write a little desktop widget for myself, namely a calendar which neatly displays my university calendar as a sort of timetable. I'm on Kubuntu 20.04, so I guess I'll have to use QML for that... I've followed this tutorial: https://develop.kde.org/docs/plasma/widget/ to create the basic look of the calendar, but now I'm lost as to how to implement the logic.

Basically I'd want to fetch the data from the online iCal, parse it and display it in my widget (and update about every hour or so). I guess I could write a python script for the first part, but I still haven't got the slightest clue how to implement displaying the dates in the QML widget (since QML is probably only supposed to handle the graphics, but how can I implement the logic then?). I've searched the web for a long time now, and looked at a lot of the preinstalled widgets, but that hasn't really helped that much. All of those are also only written in QML, no C++ as far as I could tell... So how could I go about this?

EDIT: By logic I mean: How can I express something like "If there is a calendar entry on monday at 15:30, construct a rectangle at the appropriate position in the widget and give it a fitting label"

My code so far:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import org.kde.plasma.components 3.0 as PlasmaComponents

RowLayout {
    spacing: 0
    
    Layout.preferredWidth: 640 * units.devicePixelRatio
    Layout.preferredHeight: 480 * units.devicePixelRatio
    
    Rectangle {
        //day header
        Rectangle {
            PlasmaComponents.Label {
                text: "Monday"
                width: parent.width
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                height: parent.height
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "#000"
            border.width: 1
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height / 12   
        }
        //day body
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "#000"
        border.width: 1
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
    Rectangle {
        //day header
        Rectangle {
            PlasmaComponents.Label {
                text: "Tuesday"
                width: parent.width
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                height: parent.height
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "#000"
            border.width: 1
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height / 12   
        }
        //day body
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "#000"
        border.width: 1
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
    Rectangle {
        //day header
        Rectangle {
            PlasmaComponents.Label {
                text: "Wednesday"
                width: parent.width
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                height: parent.height
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "#000"
            border.width: 1
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height / 12   
        }
        //day body
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "#000"
        border.width: 1
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
    Rectangle {
        //day header
        Rectangle {
            PlasmaComponents.Label {
                text: "Thursday"
                width: parent.width
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                height: parent.height
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "#000"
            border.width: 1
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height / 12   
        }
        //day body
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "#000"
        border.width: 1
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
    Rectangle {
        //day header
        Rectangle {
            PlasmaComponents.Label {
                text: "Friday"
                width: parent.width
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                height: parent.height
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "#000"
            border.width: 1
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height / 12   
        }
        //day body
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "#000"
        border.width: 1
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
}
```

Comment: QML is a kind of subset of Javascript so you can create your logic in pure QML. Another option is extending QML with C++. It's not clear from your question what do you mean by _logic_. Please update your question with more info.

Comment: What exactly do you not know how to do?  And what do you mean by "logic"? QML is based on javascript so it can do most of what javascript can. There are examples on the page you referenced - have you read through them and understood how they work? By "iCal" do you mean RFC5545 data format, Apple Calendar app, TCL/Tk "ical" package or some sort of calendar website? What kind of API and data format does your web server have? In general, data can be downloaded through `XmlHttpRequest()` even if it's not XML or HTTP, and then parsed with XML/JSON parser or by writing a line-by-line string parser.

Answer (score 1):

there are in my opinion to ways to do this. The first one is as some comments allready mentioned using simple JavaScript to fetch the data from iCal and then parse it. THe other option is using C++ to do the same thing.

Because I am not that experienced in C++ I will only explaine the JavaScript and QML way.
You can start by simple creating a JavaScript file and writing a XMLhttpRequest in it.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp
The Link above shows you a simple way to write a XMLhttpRequest in JavaScript. But the basic code for all the people that do not want to open up the link is this.

```
function getData(url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            return xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.open("Get", url);
    xhr.send();
}
```

This is as I allready said a very simple way of doing it. Next when you have the data, you can parse it. If you get data in a JSON format, the best way to do it would be to just use the normal JSON.parse() function build in Qt. And then you can plugin the data into a normal Model, like a ListModel. If the Data is not in a JSON format or the JSON is not so simple to pick apart, then you can also use the JSONListModel, check it out here: https://wiki.qt.io/JSONListModel
Basicly it is a simple ListModel that directly works with a JSON string. But you can also use the C++ JSON parser, which I unfortunatly have 0 experience with but the documentation can be found here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html

Now I hope that I could help you a little with your problem. If not leave a comment.

YOu might also want to check out my book about Qt 6, there you can find a lot more info about Qt, using the Components Qt provides and for instance JSON and C++ Integration if you need that. The book can be found here: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08XLLDZSG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08XLLDZSG)